# C Algorithm for bounded tree traversal

Tags: c, tree, binary-search-tree

I am looking for a way to traverse an ordered binary tree with a left and right limit.
So traverse only nodes that are within a left and right bound, preferably inorder and iterative.

I tried modifying an iterative inorder implementation i found on that site: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inorder-tree-traversal-without-recursion/

The problem i am facing right now is, that i cant just say dont go left if left node <= leftBound and dont go right if node >= rightBound, cause a node smaller/bigger than a given bound can still have childen within that bound.

Comment: Then just traverse them all and don't do X for those nodes outside the bound.

Comment: I am working with pretty big trees. It would indeed be a simple solution but wouldnt it be super inefficient even if i dont do anything for nodes outside my bound?

Comment: Do not go left from X if X ≤ leftBound. You considered the criterion “left node of X ≤ leftBound,” but “X ≤ leftBound” is different. All left children of X are less than X, so if X is the left bound or greater, its left child and all its descendants are less than leftBound.